# React-Native - View config not found for name "Custom Tag"

Tags: react-native, jsx

I am using react-native-navigation v2 and every component needs to be registered into the navigation by calling registerComponent(). However, I found myself having 500 lines of code where I register every component of my app using the same registerComponent structure with the only difference of using different jsx tag for every component I register, like so:

```
import ItemsList from './src/components/ItemsList';
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reduxStore from "./src/store";

Navigation.registerComponent(
  "app.ItemsList",
  () => props => (
    <Provider store={reduxStore}>
      <ItemsList {...props} />
    </Provider>
  ),
  () => ItemsList
);
+++ 35 more components almost exactly just like this one
```

Now, in order to reduce that huge amount of identical code, I've decided to write an IIFE that maps through an array of objects(components) that look like:

```
[...,
  {
    name: "ItemsList",
    component: ItemsList
  },
...]
```

then calls registerComponent on every item and returns the JSX I need, like so:

```
(function componentsRegistration() {
  return components.map(({ name, component }) => {
    const Tag = name;
    Navigation.registerComponent(
      `app.${name}`,
      () => props => (
        <Provider store={reduxStore}>
          <Tag {...props} />
        </Provider>
      ),
      () => component
    );
  });
})()
```

After this specific manipulation, my app doesn't render anymore. Instead it throws the "Invariant Violation: View config is not found for name ItemsList". I think I've made all of this respecting the React commandments (capital letter jsx tag, etc.), however can't get it to work. If anyone could, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] I was getting an error because I was trying to pass a string with the component name instead of the component itself.

The right way to do it would be:

```
const Tag = component;
```

instead of:

```
const Tag = name;
```